# hyperlink not working in excel web access sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, excel, hyperlink

I posted an excel web access on my SharePoint, the file contain a list of hyperlinks to a Library of documents. the file uploaded fine, but all the hyperlinks are unaccesible. Is there a way to keep the hyperlinks active in excel web access?

Answer (score 0):

Per my testing, the hyperlinks need to start with the protocol "http://" or "https://".

If the link address does not have a protocol, it does not works as a hyperlink in the Excel Web Access web part.

Try adding the link using `=HYPERLINK("http://www.bing.com","Test")`,

and try using Insert > Hyperlink, compare the results.

[image]

Besides, try unchecking the "Update links on save" checkbox before adding hyperlinks, see if it works.

File -> Options -> Advanced -> Under General, click Web Options -> On the Files tab, click to clear the Update links on save check box.

[image]